# error -1004 Could not connect to the server, when using an iOS device

Tags: ios, localhost, httprequest

I am fetching image from server on iOS simulator and I found this location to be working

```
  let s = "http://localhost/sc.png"
```

I also tried using IP address of my computer instead of localhost. No error, but the image isn't fetched.

I tried the same on real device and I get an error

```
-1004 "Could not connect to the server.
```

What should I use instead of my current address?

CODE:

```
@IBAction func startRequest(sender: AnyObject) {
        let s = "http://localhost/sc.png"
        let url = NSURL(string:s)!

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url) {
            (loc:NSURL?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            let status = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            if status != 200 {
                print("response status: \(status)")
                return
            }
            let d = NSData(contentsOfURL:loc!)!
            let im = UIImage(data:d)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.imageView.image = im
                print("sdjsjdhsdhsd")
            }
        }
        task.resume()




    }
```

Comment: Updating your question with some relevant code would be quite helpful.

Comment: And are you really using `localhost`? That refers to the same device the code is running on.

Comment: I also used my IP address of my computer. it doesn't work either although no error is thrown. What should be used instead?